# What is the simplest way in C++98 to get and continue to call a class method, the type of which the current class does not know?

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns

Example:
Suppose we are developing a simple graphical interface:

We have windows and controls. What do we want:

- There is a base window class that implements the GUI functionality
  hidden from the user.
- From the base window, the user inherits a specific window.
- There is a class of a button, an instance of which the user can add to his window.
- **The user can transfer the method of his window to button, and it will be executed when clicking this button.**

I'm interested in how to reach the last point.

Kind of pseudo-code:

```
class BaseWindow;

class Button
{
public:
            Button(BaseWindow* parent)
            {
                        parent->AddButton(this);
            }

            void SetBehavior(/*Owners pointer and owner's methos*/)
            {
                        /* Save Owner pointer and owner's method*/
            }

            void Clicked(/*coords*/)
            {
                        if(/*coords == my coords*/)
                        {
                                    /*Call Owner's method*/
                        }
            }
};

class BaseWindow
{
            vector<Button*> Buttons;

            WindowClicked(/*coords*/)
            {
                    for (std::vector<Button*>::iterator it = Buttons.begin(); it != Buttons.end(); ++it) 
                    {
                                it->Clicked(/*coords*/);
                    }
            }

public:
            void AddButton(Button* butt)
            {
                            Buttons<<butt;
            }

};

class UserWindow:public BaseWindow
{
            Button MyButton;
public:
            void FunctionForButton(Button* butt){ cout<<"Say Hello, my sweet button";}

            UserWindow():MyButton(this)
            {
                        MyButton.SetBehavior(/*Put here my Function for Button and my pointer*/);
            }
};
```

Comment: My bad, I forgot that it without using C++11 standart, only C++98. I will edit my question.

Comment: `for(auto i:Buttons)`... that is C++11...

Comment: "Kind of pseudo-code", but ok, I'm edited

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using some "pure" abstract classes (nice to conceptually think of as *interfaces* so I'll call them that!) to create an ad hoc protocol for handling these events.

Examples:

```
class IEventHandler
{
public:
    virtual ~IEventHandler() { }
    virtual void HandleEvent(IEventData* const pEventData) = 0;
};
```

`IEventHandler` provides a simple abstract base class interface for handling events, declaring a method called `HandleEvent`, accepting an argument of pointer to `IEventData`.

```
class IEventData
{
public:
    virtual ~IEventData() = 0;
};

inline IEventData::~IEventData()
{
}
```

`IEventData` provides a simple abstract base class interface for providing data to `IEventHandler::HandleEvent`.

Then (using your original pseudo-code as a starting point, embellished with more pseudo-code :-)):

```
class BaseWindow;

class Button
{
public:
            Button(BaseWindow* parent)
            : pEventHandler_(NULL)
            {
                        parent->AddButton(this);
            }

            void SetBehavior(IEventHandler* pEventHandler)
            {
                        /* Save Owner pointer and owner's method*/
                        pEventHandler_ = pEventHandler;
            }

            void Clicked(/*coords*/)
            {
                        if(/*coords == my coords*/)
                        {
                                    IEventData* pData = new CoordinateEventData(/*coords*/);
                                    /*Call Owner's method*/
                                    pEventHandler_->HandleEvent(pData);
                                    delete pData; /* if ownership not transferred to handler */
                        }
            }
protected:
            IEventHandler* pEventHandler_;
};

class BaseWindow
{
            vector<Button*> Buttons;

            WindowClicked(/*coords*/)
            {
                    for(auto i:Buttons)
                    {
                                i->Clicked(/*coords*/);
                    }
            }

public:
            void AddButton(Button* butt)
            {
                            Buttons<<butt;
            }

};

class UserWindow:public BaseWindow
{
            Button MyButton;
public:
            void FunctionForButton(Button* butt){ cout<<"Say Hello, my sweet button";}

            UserWindow():MyButton(this)
            {
                        IEventHandler* pHandler = new CoordinateEventHandler(/*things and stuff*/);
                        MyButton.SetBehavior(pHandler);
            }
};
```

You would package the data applicable to the coordinates from your `Button::Clicked` method into the `CoordinateEventData`.

You would transition/adapt the implementation of your `UserWindow::FunctionForButton` method to the `CoordinateEventHandler::HandleEvent` method.

Alternately, you could have `UserWindow` "implement" (derive from) `IEventHandler` and implement `IEventHandler::HandleEvent` using the code from (or by calling) `UserWindow::FunctionForButton`, and use `MyButton.SetBehavior(this)` to wire it up.

As usual, you'll want to be mindful of pointer ownership to avoid leaks.

Hope that gives you some ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::function<ReturnCode(Args...)>`.

Suppose you have a UI context struct:

```
struct UI_context {
  mouse_position mouse;
  keyboard_state keyboard;
};
```

And suppose the button supports a few kinds of actions:

```
struct button_trigger {
  bool click;
  bool enter;
  bool touch;
  bool pen;
};
```

and there are a few things you can ask the button to do:

```
struct click_result {
  bool toggle;
  bool flash;
  bool wiggle;
};
```

then you'd store a `std::function< click_result( button_trigger, UI_context ) >`.

Of course, a `std::function<void()>` might be all you want.  Or a `std::function<void(mouse_location)>`.

Anything with an `operator()` that is compatible with the signature you provide `std::function` will work.  A function pointer or a lambda are the two most common.

You may want to add a way to register and remove callbacks, and/or have a token system.

Comment: My bad, I forgot that it without using C++11 standart, only C++98. I will edit my question.

Comment: @Ep1c you can write a `std::function<some_fixed_signature>` in C++98 or use a `boost::function`.  Practically, this is 2017, using a 19 year old standard for C++ is probably your biggest problem.

Comment: I completely agree with you if programming under modern PCs, but using C ++ 98 is very common in microcontroller programming.